# Mongo .net client schema evolution error

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

i am using mongo .net client and using the collection to objects features. issue i have come across in schema evolution

when i rename a field in my class for example change field name from Comment to Comments and i make this change in my class, i get an exception from Mongo when i perform a fetch.

my expectation is that mongo client will ignore fields that exists in the collection but doesnt exists in my .net class.

will be happy if its possible without doing the transformation between bson and .net class.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue to use the old name you could use the `BsonElement` attribute:

```
class Demo {
    [BsonElement("Comment")]
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Using that syntax would tell the MongoDB C# driver to find the data for the `Comments` property/field in a field in the document in a field named `Comment`. That would mean that you don't need to worry about moving/copying the data from the old location. It's often used so that you can use longer friendly names in source code, while minimizing the actual BSON Document size (as the full property name is always stored in the document in the database collection). When shortening, you might for example just use:

```
[BsonElement("c")]
public string Comments { get; set; }
```

Some of the MongoDB drivers don't have this functionality (and I wish they did!).

Secondly, you could also just add a special attribute to your class ignore all unknown elements for the class and not thrown an exception:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public Demo {
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Then, if a field named `Comment` is found, but can't be matched to a property of your C# class, it will be ignored. I'll often use this during development as the schema changes, but then remove it later so that I can catch unexpected fields.

Or you can also use the `BsonClassMap` to make similar changes:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Demo>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
});
```

There are even some more options documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#handling-schema-changes) if you want complete control.